# Getting issue to convert in JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am getting the response as mentioned below:

AFMomFormDetails now has `{\"sigName\":\"qwer\",\"contName\":\"asdf\",\"signature\":\"zxcv\"}` after the move

```
var resStr = response;
var retStr = resStr.substring(resStr.indexOf("{"), resStr.indexOf("}")+1);
var strObj  = retStr.replace(/\\/g, "");
$scope.fdetails=JSON.stringify(strObj);
```

I am unable to bind the values in angularjs. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON, not `JSON.stringify`. (If the string is as shown, you don't need to pre-process it, either.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Can you send sample code for parser

Comment: *Look at* the answers to the question linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a json string, try parsing it with `JSON.parse()`, it will give you an object. Then bind this object to `$scope.fdetails`.

```js
var resStr = '{\"sigName\":\"qwer\",\"contName\":\"asdf\",\"signature\":\"zxcv\"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(resStr)
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: I was adding the explanation. Now, I have added the explanation.

Comment: Posting incomplete answers to "get on the board" ahead of others is impolite. Separately, as the question is a **blatant** duplicate, the right course of action is to find a dupe target and vote to close.

Comment: I will keep this in mind next time adding answer.